# Changing pixel size in 'asc' file using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, resampling, maxent

I have soil data and BioClim data from Australia

**soil data**:

```
rows 2200
columns 1400
pixel size 0.0025, -0.0025 255
```

**BioClim data**:

```
rows 660 
columsn 420 
pixel size 0.00833333, -0.00833333
```

I am using QGIS but happy to use commandline or Python. How can I resample the soil data to match the pixel size of the BioClim data? I would like to add this to my Maxent model and I am sure it needs to be the same resolution.

I have looked for duplicate questions but could not see anything that specifically did this.

Answer (score 4):

`gdalwarp -tr` should deliver what you want.

`gdal_translate -outsize` does basically the same thing, if both datasets share the same extent.

In QGIS, `Raster -> Projections -> Warp`and `Raster -> Conversions -> Translate` call the same functions. For the first one, you have to edit the command line to get the `-tr` option.

You might have to do additional steps if the cell extent must match exactly.

Comment: I used:

'gdalwarp -of VRT -r average -tr 0.00833333,0.00833333 soils1.asc interim.vrt' then
'gdal_translate -of AAIGrid interim.vrt soils.asc'

However Maxent still won't run on these files as it gives an error "Bio1_49_new.asc and soils.asc have different dimensions"

Comment: FILE Bio1_49_new.asc

   #DRIVER# 
GDAL provider 
AAIGrid
Arc/Info ASCII Grid
   #DATASET DESCRIPTION#
Bio1_49_new.asc
   #DIMENSIONS#
X: 660 Y: 420 Bands: 1
   #ORIGIN#
114.5,-32
   #PIXEL SIZE#
0.00833333,-0.00833333
   #NO DATA VALUE#
-9999
   #DATA TYPE#
Float64 - Sixty four bit floating point
   #LAYER SPATIAL REFERENCE SYSTEM#
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
   #LAYER EXTENT (layer original source protection)#
114.5000000000029985,-35.5000000000029985 : 119.9999999997830002,-32.0000000001429967

Comment: FILE Soils

   #DRIVER# 
GDAL provider 
AAIGrid
Arc/Info ASCII Grid
   #DATASET DESCRIPTION#
soils.asc
   #DIMENSIONS#
X: 660 Y: 420 Bands: 1
   #ORIGIN#
114.5,-32
   #PIXEL SIZE#
0.00833333,-0.00833333
   #NO DATA VALUE#
-9999
   #DATA TYPE#
Float64 - Sixty four bit floating point
   #LAYER SPATIAL REFERENCE SYSTEM#
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
   #LAYER EXTENT (layer original source protection)#
114.4999990000000025,-35.4999893999999969 : 119.9999968000000052,-31.9999907999999955

Comment: Do these files need to be EXACTLY the same dimensions for MaxEnt to run? I have used: gdal_translate -projwin 114.5 -30.0 120.0 -35.5 -of AAIGrid file1 file2 to clip the file down after the rescaling.

Comment: You could use `gdal_translate -a_ullr 114.5 -30 120 -35.5` on both files as well. I have no experience with MaxEnt.

Answer (score 2):

I used `gdalwarp` for exactly same purpose. From **QGIS version 2.12** there is also built-in **Raster alignment tool** (`Raster -> Raster alignment tool`) - it can clip, resample and reproject rasters to match other raster. For more info see changelog here: http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog212/#feature-raster-alignment-tool

edit:
To run MaxEnt all environmental data **must have the exactly same extent, cell size** and coordinate system. So when using `gdalwarp` you have to specify extent `-te` and resolution `-tr` (or `-ts` for size in pixels).

For example I was using:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te 64.9916666666670011 35.0083333333329989 84.9916666658670010 45.0083333329329989 -ts 2400 1200 -r cubic -dstnodata -9999 LC_asia.tif LC_asia2.tif
```

Comment: The Raster Alignment Tool sounds perfect for what I need to do. However I can't see in in Qgis 2.4 Chigiak. Any ideas why - do I need to install it?

Comment: It's new feature for QGIS 2.12 Lyon. To get this feature you have to install this version.

Comment: Ah... I was reading that as 2.1.2 thinking "I've got 2.four which is a later version". You are referring to '2.twelve'! I will get that installed tomorrow. Thanks for your help.