# Fixing raster.asc to work with Maxent?

Tags: maxent

How to fix the raster.asc to work with Maxent?

Running Maxent with raster from WorldClim and others as Altitude, LandCover, etc. I have problems because shows up one error (have different geographic dimensions). I have been trying to fix that in several ways, probing that the spatial reference is the same, the last thing I did was to clip the raster with the same extent introducing manually the coordinates. I am not sure if is neccesary exactly the same coordinates in the four points for the whole set of rasters. Maxent works with the 19 worldclim variables but I need to include altitude, landcover, etc, but I have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To run MaxEnt **all** environmental data **must have** the exactly **same extent, cell size and coordinate system**.

You can achieve this several ways (QGIS, GDAL, R, ...) look at [Changing pixel size in 'asc' file using Qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177083/changing-pixel-size-in-asc-file-using-qgis). If you are familiar with `gdal` you can check the extent of `.asc` data with `gdalinfo`.